# Will the pair be complete after map insertion?

Tags: c++, dictionary, mapping

I am inserting elements in a map avoiding duplicates, so I've written this code

```cpp
std::unordered_map<size_t, size_t> idToPos;
for (it : list) {
    auto itPos = idToPos.find(it.id());
    if (itPos==idToPos.end()) {
        idToPos[itPos->first] = idToPos.size();
        do_something_else();
    }
}
```

The question is, if `itPos==idToPos.end()` is true, will `itPos->second` yield the same result as `idToPos[itPos->first]` given `idToPos` is an `unordered_map`?

Comment: Why do you not just use `idToPos[it.id()] = idToPos.size()`?

Comment: And do you really need to do the check? unordered_map will take care of not getting duplicate ids...

Comment: @Lasersköld: `idToPos.emplace(it.id, idToPos.size());` as existing objects are not overwritten.

Comment: @Lasersköld the problem was that getting the id can be costly. However, I see my blunder, since if ```itPos==idToPos.end()``` then looking for ```first``` or ```second``` makes no sense.

Comment: @Jarod42 Shouldn't it be ```try_emplace``` rather than ```emplace```?

Comment: @Maxence1402, for `std::size_t` key and value it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

When `itPos==idToPos.end()`, `itPos->first` is undefined, which leads to [Undefined Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/5470596).

You want

```
std::unordered_map<size_t, size_t> idToPos;
for (it : list) {
    auto itPos = idToPos.find(it.id());
    if (itPos==idToPos.end()) idToPos[it.id()] = idToPos.size();
}
```

Comment: What does UB mean?

Comment: My bad, UB means Undefined Behaviour. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid getting the id twice? Depending on the element it can be costly. I guess I can still use a new variable

Comment: `.emplace()` will handle duplicates, there is no need to use `.find` (searching the map twice, first time in `find`, second time in `[]`).

Comment: @Evg I did not specify though that I want to do something else if and only if the key isn't present. I read that ```emplace``` will return a pair whose second element is a boolean telling if the key is absent, is that it?

Comment: @Maxence1402, that's true.